# Can a separable Banach space have a total subset?

Tags: functional-analysis

I will like to know whether a separable Banach space can have a total subset?

A separable Banach space has a countable dense subset V, but can we do something to make V

total?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A dense subset is automatically total, since every set is contained in its linear span.

Answer (score 2):

After the suggestion from Daniel Fischer, here is my attempt:

Since $V$ is dense in Banach Space $X$, then

$$V \subset span(V) \subset X$$
$$\therefore X=\overline{V}\subset\overline{span(V)}\subset X$$
$$\therefore X=\overline{V}=\overline{span(V)}= X$$
$\therefore V$ is also the total set required.

Please advise on any mistakes made.

Thank you.